# I try to curl two specific domains. it works on personal Ubuntu but not work on Amazon EC2 instance. AND I TRY ALL INSTANCES IN THE USA

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, dns, ubuntu-14.04

I post two question before and didn't get a good answer. I send the issue to Amazon Tech Support and they cannot solve it. Then already forward the issue to their back-end developer team.

I try to curl these two URLs: 1.http://legislature.vermont.gov/; 2.http://nebraskalegislature.gov/. Both of them are able to set up connection on my personal Ubuntu. But Here is the situation on EC2 instance. All the instance pass either one. None of them pass both ....

```
http://legislature.vermont.gov/
```

- us-east-1b (fail)
- us-east-1c (fail)
- us-east-1d (pass)
- us-east-1e (fail)
- us-west-1a (fail)
- us-west-1c (pass)
- us-west-2a (pass)
- us-west-2b (pass)

  http://nebraskalegislature.gov/
- us-east-1b (fail)
- us-east-1c (pass)
- us-east-1d (fail)
- us-east-1e (pass)
- us-west-2a (fail)
- us-west-2b (fail)
- us-west-2c (pass)
- us-west-1a (pass)
- us-west-1c (fail)

Comment: What is the exact message you are getting when it fails?

Comment: Important side-note for anyone attempting to replicate this issue: availability zone labels (e.g. us-east-1c) are randomized across AWS account boundaries.  This means "my" us-east-1c *might be* the same availability zone "your" us-east-1c, but it also might be "your" us-east-1b, -1d, -1e, etc., and (less likely) it might not correspond to any availability zone your account can access.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for adding the note

Comment: ENOUGH WITH THE SHOUTING ALREADY PEOPLE ARE TRYING TO SLEEP

Comment: @EJP But there is still no solution for that. And I am already waiting for Amazon guys for few days. I tried to change to another DNS server two weeks ago. It just doesn't work

Comment: I don't know why you're addressing that comment to me. I haven't stated anything about a solution. I am complaining about your inappropriate use of all capitals. If you think it will attract more attention other than the adverse kind you are almost certainly mistaken. Your question also appears to be off-topic.

Comment: @EJP gotcha.. Any suggestion so that I can address a correct topic? I am kind of new to Stackflow. I am sorry for interrupting you. Yeah. In my previous two questions, I didn't use the capitals..

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting different CURL results from globally dispersed hosts, after making a DNS change to the zone record, it is very likely a [DNS Caching issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/82251/why-is-it-called-dns-propagation).

Due to the distributed nature of DNS hosts and DNS caching architecture, it is common for changes to DNS records to not propagate throughout the network immediately.  That is likely what you are seeing.

DNS changes require that all caches expire and refresh after the [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) (Time To Live) set for the record and/or the zone itself.

Give it an hour or two.  In some cases changes can take 24 hours to propagate.

Comment: From AWS Tech suppor, it is not a DNS caching issue. They said the DNS server somehow block the IP address from Amazon which also doesn't make sense to me. From the result, you can tell, it is always one of the url works but another doesn't work. AND THE IMPORTANT thing is there is one day on which both url works on my east-1c zone but it doesn't work again any more a few hours latter.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that the answer from AWS tech support is correct -- not only is it not a DNS caching issue, as was suggested, but it also appears to be the case the destination name servers are not responding to requests from the DNS resolvers that EC2 instances use (which vary by region, and presumably also by availability zone).

> also doesn't make sense to me.

Perhaps not, but that's what the evidence suggests.

You didn't post the actual error you see, but here's what I see in us-east-1:

```
$ curl -v http://legislature.vermont.gov
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for legislature.vermont.gov:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'legislature.vermont.gov'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'legislature.vermont.gov'
```

Using `dig` and `nslookup` fails similarly.  The built-in resolvers in EC2 can't reach the name servers for those domains.

However, if you change your name server inside the EC2 instance to use an external DNS server, such as Google public DNS 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4, you'll find that it does work.

While it's theoretically *possible* the issue is the result of a problem with the AWS resolvers, it seems far more likely the problems exist in the infrastructure hosting the DNS for those domains.

Comment: Hey, sorry for replying late. Actually, I tried to change the DNS server to external DNS server of which I post the situation in my previous two questions. Can I ask the correct way to change the DNS server? I tried to modify the sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf and add the name server on the top of this file. nameserver 8.8.8.8. And it just doesn't work on me. I tried to restart the server. The url still doesn't work. I remember it is a temporary solution and if you restart the machine, the resolv.conf will be over-write.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to switch to another DNS server two weeks ago. I `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf` and add the `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, `nameserver 8.8.4.4`. On top of the file. It just doesn't work. I am already spending money on Amazon Tech support and waiting for them for two weeks. There is no solution yet. They said the DNS server side somehow block the Amazon IP range and they are trying to figure it out.

Is the way I modified the resolv.conf correct?